# MASM0015 ; Webservice HandlerTubeFactory exception

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, weblogic12c

I am trying to create webservice chain that one calls to another. I have created first service and deployed on weblogic12c succesfully. 
There is below exception when first webservice was trying to call outer webservice.

```
----notifyAbout----
 WSTestOuter outer = new WSTestOuter(getWsdlLocation(), new QName("http://www.example.com/abcd/soa/wsdl", "WSTestOuter"));
 WSTestOuterPort outerPort =outer.getWSTestOuterPort();
```

Exception;

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: MASM0015: Class [ com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.HandlerTubeFactory ] does not implement [ com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.dev.TubeFactory ] interface
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.TubeCreator.<init>(TubeCreator.java:63)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController.initializeTubeCreators(TubelineAssemblyController.java:116)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController.getTubeCreators(TubelineAssemblyController.java:79)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.MetroTubelineAssembler.createClient(MetroTubelineAssembler.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.createPipeline(Stub.java:328)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:295)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:228)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getStubHandler(WSServiceDelegate.java:814)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:803)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:436)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:404)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:459)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:463)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:188)
    at com.xyz.abcd.soa.hop.ws.impl.WSTest.notifyAbout(WSTest.java:126)
```

Is there any recommendation that i can try?

Comment: What are the jars you are using? Whats the class path ?

Comment: Is it soved ? If so how ?

Comment: @Chandu i could not solve problem. That's why i changed it to .SOAPConnection.call

Comment: Issue is because of jars of weblogic 12c. They break jas-ws client. How did u change SOAPConnection.call ?

Comment: i have added required jar with names jaxb-api-2.2.3.jar, jaxws-api-2.2.1.jar and webservices*** jar . After all there was no changes about error. So i decided to use SAAJ.

Answer (score 1):

Weblogic 12c installation will have com.oracle.webservices.wls.jaxws-wlswss-client.jar. Put this in CLASSPATH. It should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've added `com.oracle.webservices.wls.jaxws-wlswss-client.jar` in the project and my issue was resolved.

Comment: Hi @Rahul Pardeshi and thanks for the suggestion. What if I have the client developed in a Maven project? what is the relevant dependency that I am missing? Thanks!