# MASM0015, jaxws.HandlerTubeFactory doesn't implement dev.TubeFactory interface intellij

Tags: maven, web-services, jax-ws

I tried to create a simple webservice that a client call to a server. But when i run this main from client:

```
HelloService service = new HelloService();
Hello hello = service.getHelloPort();
System.out.println(hello.greeting("root", "123"));
```

It's throw this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: MASM0015: Class [ com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.HandlerTubeFactory ] does not implement [ com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.dev.TubeFactory ] interface
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.TubeCreator.<init>(TubeCreator.java:63)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController.initializeTubeCreators(TubelineAssemblyController.java:116)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController.getTubeCreators(TubelineAssemblyController.java:79)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.MetroTubelineAssembler.createClient(MetroTubelineAssembler.java:103)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.createPipeline(Stub.java:328)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:295)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:228)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:243)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:84)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getStubHandler(WSServiceDelegate.java:814)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:803)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:436)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:404)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:386)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:119)
at com.example.webclient.HelloService.getHelloPort(HelloService.java:72)
at com.example.webclient.HelloClient.main(HelloClient.java:6)
```

The code that error are:

```
Hello hello = service.getHelloPort();
```

And the `getHelloPort()` function:

```
@WebEndpoint(name = "HelloPort")
public Hello getHelloPort() {
    return super.getPort(new QName("http://webserver.example.com/", "HelloPort"), Hello.class);
}
```

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
              https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>Prob6</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Prob6</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I got the same problem here and follow this but still can't solve it
[MASM0015 ; Webservice HandlerTubeFactory exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350821/masm0015-webservice-handlertubefactory-exception)

Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Which application server are you using?

If this is weblogic 12c, then in my case the issue was solved as described here [MASM0015 ; Webservice HandlerTubeFactory exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350821/masm0015-webservice-handlertubefactory-exception)

Also try to exclude the JAX-WS dependencies, they may be make some mess, if you really try to solve this problem for Oracle WebLogic. My variant is working when I use the Java8 default JAX-WS implementation in the combination with the given Weblogic client library.